# ubuntu 16.04 freezing after login

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 on a razer stealth rz09 with nvidia gtx1060 gpu (this gpu being the reason i got the machine).  The system freezes often upon login, with both the current and previous kernels.  If I use one of the grub options to do a dpkg repair occasionally I am able to boot, and I've managed to do  apt-get update and upgrade but still hit the boot hang most of the time. I have a windows partition from which I am writing this but would like to continue with linux since the servers I work off are all linux.  This is the second time I've installed linux on this machine, the first time getting stuck after attempting a cuda install - but this time the drivers are all stock! I currently boot with 'secure boot disabled' fwiw.  Anyway if someone has some pointers I would appreciate it

Comment: What is the feedback from the console?

Comment: Some of the answers here may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/q/4408/507051

Comment: can you provide the contents of /var/log/boot?

Comment: /var/log/boot.log after a succesful login (no freeze ) pasted  [here](https://pastebin.com/jd1fjgMN) and dmesg output pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/J81AY9Tr)  .  This was after a windows boot, which I have heard temporarily allows a subsequent  boot into linux.  I'll try rebooting now and see if it hangs again.   @RamanSailopal I wasnt clear on what kind of feedback you were after

Comment: Press F3 when the system boots, this will switch you from the boot splash screen to the console messages.

Comment: the 'garage effect' seems to be in force (take your car to the mechanic and the problem disappears), so far 3 boots,  no hang, and I even have an external screen working (previously this wasnt). If it happens again I will try [REISUB](http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) and such to get output of dmesg and boot.log

Comment: I put the [Xorg.failsafe.log](https://pastebin.com/Scp64uXX) after a freeze/reboot with failsafe X up, if that helps anyone understand the problem.

Comment: The only thing I saw in dmesg was this line:  could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2

Comment: after a succesfull boot I see the folowing lines in red from dmesg: [    3.101148] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 00d054 00000007 (1b408216)
,  [    3.450695] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to create kernel channel, -22
, [    4.174166] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2

Comment: In bios I canceled 'fast boot' (which apparently loads efi/vga display driver) and put uefi options to be loaded first  .  After a few good boots the freeze happened again (possibly related to a freeze on shutdown?  I do sudo shutdown -r now , or close the lid, and system freezes)

Comment: this may possibly relate to another freeze on shutdown - when I try shutdown -r now , the system often freezes, and boots after those freezes likewise freeze every time I've looked for this sequence

Comment: Xorg.failsafe.log after a failed boot and then a failsafe boot [here](https://pastebin.com/ZW8aa7yj)

Answer (score 1):

Using 'nomodeset' in grub as described  [here](https://www.linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/rosa/nomodeset_bios.webm) and then install of driver using standard install worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem: My PC was freezing randomly. I tried Ubuntu 16, 17 and 18.04 and everything was the same. I tried several drivers and didn't get a solution. I tried several solutions that I found in the forums and got bad and harmful results.

My solution was: I stopped using the graphical nvidia card, removed it and now I'm using the integrated Intel HD graphics card (Intel® HD Graphics 530 card (Skylake GT2)) and all the problems were solved!

Comment: see reply above - nomodeset in grub seems to do the trick

Comment: Not for me. My Nvidia graphic Card works fine with Windows, but it doesn work with Ubuntu 17 neither beta 18.04, so the problems are the drivers in Ubuntu. I had removed Nvidia graphic Card and now I using the integrated Intel graphics processor (-Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) -) and the problem was gone.

Well, for me this is the real solution while Ubuntu and partners find the solution of the problem with this graphics card